# Furnace end bell burned out twice in 4 years

Tags: repair, furnace

We moved into a house with a 12 year old goodman (Xenon brand but I was told goodman parts) and two end bells on the furnace fan motor have burned out now (I know from the old owners receipts it happened before). The folks who repaired can't tell me why...that I seem to have a lemon. I use MERV 11 filters, have the furnace cleaned annually and vents cleaned last year. Any thoughts on what might cause this and anything I could look into so we don't have this happen again. @chris mentions airflow potentially...how do I know if Adjustments are needed? 
Also, I read that the newer furnace filters MERV 11 and under have good airflow...is there a way to test my system for airflow and how the filter way to affecting this? I can easily change air filters if that is this is the consensus though.
I don't know if this means anything or not, but we also have water dripping out of the air return during the air conditioning season...I thought I heard repairman say that fan speed could be adjusted to fix this...any ideas?[image]

Comment: What model is this, and are you talking about a bearing burning out, or something else?

Comment: I wonder if someone "opened up" the ductwork so that you are moving more air than designed, and drawing more current - in general overloading the motor. It's a common error when someone who does not truly understand starts messing with the system balancing dampers.

Comment: To clarify, it is an ECM motor and I saw (and smelled) the end bell when it burned out. I will certainly ask my repair man about decreasing the aurflow setting if you think that is a concern...no one has mentioned this.

Comment: You can't/shouldn't decrease the airflow setting, as that would mean not enough air is passing over the heating element or burner.  That would decrease efficiency and risk damaging another part.  You MUST decrease the amount of work the motor has to do by using a higher-airflow filter, as suggested by @chris.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you have an ECM "constant flow" blower that ramps up output as high as necessary to maintain the set airflow (aka an ECM constant torque motor).  A MERV 11 filter is too restrictive for most residential systems.  In this case, the motor would compensate for the restrictive filter by running harder and hotter to maintain the airflow.  Switch to a MERV 8 filter (it's still a pretty good filter).  If your system delivers more airflow than you need, then also set the airflow selector switches in the furnace to a lower setting.  Obviously the air filter should also be changed regularly before it becomes plugged or the blower will again ramp up to a very high level to compensate.

**EDIT; Specifics related to OP's situation:**

It turns out OP has a very high performance MERV 11 filter which if correctly matched to the system might be OK.  The stamp on the side of the filter states "Airflow Capacity up to 1400 CFM."  In reality I would expect this to mean this filter might be successfully employed on a system with a 3 ton cooling capacity (3 tons / 1200 cfm).  It would not work for a larger system.

I found more detailed information on an air cleaner that uses OP's media here:

http://www.cleancomfort.com/assets/Brochures_SpecSheets/Filtration/SS-AM11-3225.pdf

The referenced unit above uses two (2) AMP-M1-1056 filters and therefore handles twice the airflow of OP's setup.  In my experience a pleated filter is near its end of life when the static pressure drop reaches about 0.2" WC.  Looking at the "AM11-3225-5 Pressure Drop vs. Air Flow Rate" chart on page 2, one sees 0.2" static pressure loss corresponds to 2600 CFM for *two* filter cartridges *when new*.  So according to this chart, 1300 CFM would be the max airflow through OP's one cartridge *when new* and if one were to run the filter at that high a flow it would need to be changed *very* frequently (at least monthly?) because it would become more restrictive as it filled with particles.

My conclusion:  If OP's system does not exceed 3 tons / 1200 CFM and OP changes the filters *monthly* (normal intervals of 3-6 months are plausible if the system is 2 tons / 800 CFM or smaller) then the existing setup is probably OK.  Otherwise switch to something less restrictive.

Comment: Just to chime in, this is exactly right.  Your filter is the problem.  I have been scolded by two different HVAC guys due to wanting to go above a MERV 8 in a residential system.  Two dogs... dust by the pound... you get the idea.  Let some air move through your system and use a filter with better flow.

Comment: We use Aprilaire No. 201 pleated paper filter elements which supposedly  have a MERV 10 rating, but the blower motor in our middle quality Carrier HVAC has lasted 24 years.  I suppose it has a standard motor rather than an ECM constant torque. Some of these innovations have unexpected negative consequences.

Comment: So, I asked my repair guy to bring a lower MERV rating filter and he said the fan didn't burn out, the end bell that controls the voltage on the fan burned. So, any ideas?  Still the filter? Thanks

Comment: The end bell is more of a variable speed drive and not just a voltage control.  It is cooled by the airflow moved by the fan and it does operate hotter when the fan is used to move air against a restriction.  High heat kills electronics faster than windings.  Mystery to me why the repair guy is balking at this concept.  Yes I still think a MERV 8 fitler is the correct choice along with setting the blower airflow lower if your duct work permits that.  Here's a youtube url on basic ECM motor construction: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5Q5mm1Nqx9U

Comment: BTW, not all "MERV 8" filters are equivalent.  The MERV rating measures the particle size removed and not the restrictiveness of the filter per-se.  In general a MERV 8 is somewhat restrictive and a MERV 11 is significantly more restrictive, but there are "high capacity" MERV 8 filters that are less restrictive than standard MERV 8 filters.  They have more surface area (higher pleat count).  Also, 2" pleated filters are typically less restrictive than 1" pleated filters if a system accepts 2" thickness.  A 2" pleated standard capacity MERV 8 is my usual selection.

Comment: @pbarrinis - regarding reducing the airflow setting.  This cannot be changed blindly.  Someone will need to measure the airflow with a meter and verify that the airflow is set appropriately for the system.  Having the airflow set higher than necessary is a waste of energy and is more work for the blower, but having the airflow set too low is also a problem.

Comment: Thanks Chris...exactly the info I was looking for! I have a deep filter now (maybe 5" thick) MERV 11 and will swap out for the same thickness MERV 8. Thanks again for clarifying this.

Comment: To clarify, the old system was for an electronic air filter which now fits a thick 5" or so deep air filter. The deep pleat MERV 11 is what I was going to replace for the MERV 8 if this is what is needed. Any recommends on this type of filter (brand or specifics for a less restrictive kind)?

Comment: A 5" thick deep pleat MERV 11 is a specialty filter.  It may be a high capacity filter and if so it would be less restrictive than a typical MERV 11.  The supplier for these should have airflow specs on the media they are selling and how it compares to a typical 2" MERV 8.  If in doubt, measure the current being drawn by the blower with its present setup and compare it to its max rating and see how much less it draws with a less restrictive MERV 8 filter you select.  Blowers are often intended to run at around 75% of the motor's maximum rating.

Comment: I cannot tell you about brand.  Metro areas often have specialty air filter supply houses and that's what I use if I have that option.

Comment: Filter says"airflow capacity up to 1400 CFM". Do you still think it should be decreased to MERV 8? I don't know this specialty filter compares...
Thanks @chris!

Comment: @Moni - please see my revised answer above.  If you want something better please hire a local professional who knows how to check airflow and blower power consumption.

Comment: Great thanks Chris. I think I'll have someone come in and look at this. Thanks again for your assistance!